# Unity is broken

Tags: 15.10

I am having some issues getting unity to work. I installed (at leat tried to install) Unity 8 and now all I have on the top menu bar is file, edit, view.

I am running Ubuntu 15.10.

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu desktop but it did not work all I have on my screen is 2 desktop icons and no menus how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it thank you I used the compiz manager and just enabled the unity plugin again all is working now